# What is a good way to check what kind of a function a function is?

Tags: functions, special-functions

i want a module or function or switch or If (whatever works), what asks if a function is an e function or a polynomial(a hole number one or fractorial), a exponential function, a logarithm function and so on.
How can i do this? And where can i find all the build-in-questions for this? I only found PolynomialQ so far. But i am not able to put it in a Switch. Maybe It's better with If?
Thanks.
The Iam Switch is just here to look good. I wanted to create functionQ like this. The Iam Switch is from the book "Programming with Mathematica" by Paul Wellin.

```
fuu[x_] := 2 x - 5 x^3
PolynomialQ[fuu[x], x]
True

Iam[expr_] := Switch[expr,
                                _Integer, "I am an integer",
                                _Rational, "I am rational",
                                _Real, "I am real",
                                _Complex, "I am complex",
                                _, "I am not a number"]

functionQ[f_] := Switch[f,
                                _PolynomialQ[f, x], "I am polynomial",
                                _, "mystical"]
Head[fuu[x]]
Plus

Iam[fuu[x]]
I am not a number

functionQ[fuu[x]]   
mystical
```

Comment: What would a function like Sqrt[x] be? If x is 2 then Sqrt[x] is an irrational number, if x is 4 then Sqrt[x] is an integer.

Comment: And what is the reason for wanting this check?

Comment: i am working on an module which shall perfom a curve sketching with an arbitrary function. I want to check first what kind of function i have. I don't know if i will need it. But it would be nice to at least give a message that states what kind of function i have, if  it is a special function. - sorry for the factorial english :D

Comment: maybe it is useless..

Comment: I think you may find [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84984/3066) relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PolynomialQ` isn't the head of your function, so your pattern won't match it in your switch statement. Instead, you can can use a conditional pattern with the `/;` operator like so:

```
functionQ[f_] := Switch[f,
    _/;PolynomialQ[f, x], "I am polynomial",
    _, "mystical"
]

functionQ[fuu[x]]

(* "I am polynomial" *)
```

You can use this operator in the form `pattern/;condition`, which only attempts to match `pattern` if `condition` evaluates to `True`.