# How to write a pattern that matches all functions

Tags: pattern-matching

What is the correct way to match a function in an expression in the way that

```
Cases[Sin[x] Cos[x], _Sin | _Cos, {0, Infinity}]
```

matches `Sin` and `Cos`?

How can I match those functions without list all function names? The following code not only matches functions, but also `List,`Plus` and so on.

```
Cases[Sin[x] Cos[x], _?(MatchQ[Head@#, _Symbol] &), Infinity]
```

Should I express this question as matching a function not in a list such as `{List, Plus, Times, ...}`?

Comment: Since `List` is a function, a pattern that matches all functions must match `List`. If you want to exclude certain functions, such as `List` from matching, look at `Except`.

Comment: Maybe `Cases[Sin[x] Cos[x], _@_, {0, Infinity}]` for single-argument functions?

Comment: There's no general way to tell what is a *function* in Mathematica.

Comment: @m_goldberg So this is a silly question. I must define what function I want to match or what I do not want to match, before I can match them.

Comment: @kguler This is a good solution, since most of the function normally referred to take only one argument.

Comment: There is really no way of doing what you want without formulating a definition of what heads are to classified as 'functions` or what heads are to be excluded. The second may be easier, which is why I recommended looking at `Exclude`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Cases[Sin[x] Cos[x], _@_, {0, Infinity}]
(* {Cos[x], Sin[x]} *)

Cases[Sin[x] Cos[x], h_@_ :> h, {0, Infinity}]
(* {Cos, Sin} *)
```

Note: watch out for expressions that "look like" functions with a single argument:

```
Cases[Sqrt[x ] Times[Sin[x], w], h_@_ :> h, {0, Infinity}]
(* {Sin} *)
```

because

```
Sqrt[x] // FullForm
(* Power[x,Rational[1,2]] *)
```